# htons(), htonl(), ntohs(), ntohl() for enums

Tags: c

I need to send a a buffer of enums between a server and a client that could be in different platform.

But the size of enums is platform dependent, which function should I call? (`htons() or htonl()`), for example for the following enum :

```
typedef enum f_test_enum{
F0 = 0,
F1 = 1,
F2 = 2,
F3 = 3
} f_test_type;
```

Remember C Standard (C99): http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers

[...]

> Constraints The expression that defines the value of an enumeration
>   constant shall be an integer constant expression that has a value
>   representable as an int.

[...]

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration.

[EDITED]
What if my enum is:

```
typedef enum n_test_large_enum{
N1 = 0,
N2 = 1,
N2 = 2,
N120000 = 120000
} n_test_large_type;
```

or maybe:

```
typedef enum n_test_short_enum{
N0 = 0,
N1 = 1,
N2 = 2,
N60000 = 60000
} n_test_short_type;
```

When I use hton*() or ntoh*() should I take care about posible values for enums? Can I take the same behavior for all enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the value matters, as long as both sides agree on the encoding.

So, as long as your value will fit in a short, then `htons()` or `htonl()` will work, if consistent on both sides.

And if it really fits in a byte, just send that, making the whole byte-order issue vanish.

Comment: What you mean when you say consistent on both? What happen if from the side of sender the enum fits in a byte, but not on receiver?

Comment: @Rama : are you sending data between machines that have different definitions of what a "byte" is?

Comment: Well, heh, once upon a time the *byte* definition was a bit vague, but with the half-century-ago death of the all-caps-fortran-program on a CDC x600 all bytes have been at least 8 bits. You can count on that.  (Anyway, network *octets* are defined as 8 bits, and at least one standard now defines *byte* that way.)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Just different platforms, is a generic question, maybe if I don't care, for this example work well, but I'm trying to do the right thing here according to the standards.

Comment: I don't see a consistency issue here, because the parameter types and return types of the `hton*()` and `ntoh*()` functions are exact-width unsigned integers, variously `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`.  This is purposeful, of course, precisely to avoid any possibility of inconsistency with respect to types.

Comment: Edited for 2 conflicting enums.

Comment: @Rama, By consistent he meant that if you use `htons` for example on the sender side then you have to use `ntohs` on the receiver. As said, the value matters. For your `n_test_large_enum` you have to use htonl/ntohl pair. The differences between sizes of types will vanish on the call when appropriate conversions will be made if needed.